# Any way to catch the user hitting "cancel" or close on Print/Merge form - as activity list does not refresh?

Tags: civicase

The particular issue I am trying to deal with is that the print/merge form (Export Document on Manage Case) does not refresh the civiCase activities list.

This is because the user never "saves" this form, but only "cancels" it (or closes it) so there is no interaction back at the main civiCase caseView.

Any ideas for a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Good question. You can turn off popups but that doesn't fully solve it since it still stays on the page, but then at least there isn't a mismatch and when you click Cancel you can go back to Manage Case and it shows the activity.

To turn off popups go to Administer - Customize - Display Preferences and there's a checkbox "Enable Popup Forms" near the bottom.

Comment: Thanks.  Good suggestion, will try this on the users and see what they think.
You are correct, the "cancel" then does a proper refresh of the case screen and activities.